# ThreeJS & TweenJS causing ?unrelated? Warnings on material opacity access #8142

Tags: javascript, warnings, opacity

I've tried to outline the problem we are having, its just to do with the console being flooded with warnings surrounding .wrapAround and .wrapRGB when attempting to use TweenJS to access the opacity of a material.
The warning only shows once however we loop through a series of objects and apply tweens to them so we end up with a flooded console log which is quite annoying. Perhaps we are doing something wrong and there is an easy fix to stop seeing these warnings but I couldn't work it out myself was hoping you can help? :)

Here is the code for a basic example:

```
//SCENE
scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.011, 0.08 );

//RENDERER
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( 800, 600 );

//CAMERA
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, 800 / 600, 1, 30000 );
camera.position.x = 5;
camera.position.y = 10;
camera.position.z = 5;
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());

//LIGHTS
// Create Lights and add them to the scene
var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambient);

var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x999999, 2.1);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 10, 10).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

//SETUP SCENE
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10,10,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000, opacity:1, transparent:true, shading: THREE.SmoothShading});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad(-90);
scene.add(mesh);

/**
*   This way causes no warnings!
*/
/*
var opacity = mesh.material.opacity;
new TWEEN.Tween(opacity)
        .to({opacity:0}, 2000)
        .delay(10)
        .onUpdate(function(){
            mesh.material.needsUpdating = true;
            mesh.material.opacity-=0.01;
        })
        .yoyo(true)
        .repeat(Infinity)
        .start();
*/


/**
*   This way causes warnings!
*/
new TWEEN.Tween(mesh.material)
        .to({opacity:0}, 2000)
        .delay(10)
        .onUpdate(function(){
            mesh.material.needsUpdating = true;
        })
        .yoyo(true)
        .repeat(Infinity)
        .start();
loop();
```

So if you see the second tween, in which I access the mesh.material and attempt to tween the opacity I seem to get two warnings which are unrelated to opacity....

THREE.MeshBasicMaterial: .wrapAround has been removed. -three.min.js:387 THREE.MeshBasicMaterial: .wrapRGB has been removed. -three.min.js:387

This is using r73 but I believe the issue still exists in r74 too.

Is there a way to not see these warnings, as I said we apply a similar tween across an array of objects and so are shown these warnings repetitively, so floods our console with warnings.

Is there anyway to help this?

Answer (score 0):

umm i added a example page for anyway to take a look at..... http://polygonprophecy.com/html5/wrapAroundTest/ just check the console and see the flooding of warnings when using the TweenJS with ThreeJs to see code just inspect the iframe, thanks!